# Holding parameter values when report is refreshed due to custom buttons used for expand/collapse groups

Tags: sql, reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0

This may be as simple as it can't be done, but I have to ask. :) I am building a report using Report Builder 3.0.  The report contains a table which also has Grouping established.  I wanted to give the user an easy way to expand/collapse all rows of the table, so I used the method of creating a parameter with two values (0 for collapse, 1 for expand), tied the visibility of the group to the parameter using an expression in the Hidden Property for the group. Then I created two text boxes for Expand and Collapse and added the respective parameter/value in the Action in the text box properties.

At this point, everything works as intended.  Here is where I run into the issue. I added another parameter, lets just call it "Location".  The parameter is a text data type that allows multiple values and gets it available values from dataset/query in the same report.  This is where I am guessing what I want may not be possible.  When I select my Location(s), then run the report it all looks good.  However, when I click on one of the Expand/Collapse text boxes, it clears out the values that I selected for the location(s).  I am guessing this is due to the fact that the available values for the Location parameter is set via a query at run time.  Is there any way to maintain the values for the Location parameter when triggering the expand/collapse buttons?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand what you are experiencing but why not create a separate dataset for the available values e.g. `SELECT DISTINCT Location FROM myTable`. BTW: You know you can just set the visibility toggle to an existing textbox in the table to achieve the grouping expand/collapse?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I do have a separate dataset that establishes the available values for the Location variable. So when the report initially runs (using a StartDate and EndDate parameter), the Location parameter dropdown will display the available Locations.  Once I select a Location(s) and hit submit, I will then get the table of data as expected, with the rows all collapsed. Above that table of data, I have Textboxes, Expand All and Collapse All. Issue is when I select say, Expand All, the report will refresh and remove the values that I had selected for the Location parameter.

Comment: the report should not refresh when you click in a textbox unless you have done this programmatically outside of SSRS, if you use the build in functions for expaning/collapsing this is certainly the case (no refresh)

Comment: Yes, so odd.  We may be talking about the same thing, but when I click either of the text boxes, the report goes blank and the Location parameter is set back to nothing, waiting for me to select the locations.  Just strange that the Location parameter keeps getting "cleared out".

Comment: One other thing to note.  For my "Action" for the textboxes, I have it set to "Go to Report".

Comment: That explains it then, you are re-opening the report. All you need to do is select the go to the row or column group that you want to expand/collapse and select the textbox you want to acts as a trigger on the visibility tab.

Comment: That'll work!  Thanks a ton!